# Dynamic Spring form action

Tags: spring, servlets, dynamic, spring-mvc

I am trying to create a form in Spring MVC.

I would like to set *action* attribute of the `<form>` element **dynamically** using *scriplet* or something else.

MyForm:

```
<form:form id="myForm" modelAttribute="myFormBean"
    action="<%=baseUrl%>/myFormControllerPattern" name="myForm">
    <fieldset>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Age</th>
                <td><form:input path="age"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</form:form>
```

> > Error:
> >     attribute for %>" is not properly terminated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution. Thanks to *jelies*.

Added *baseUrl* in my controller like this:

```
model.setAttribute("baseUrl",url);
```

and then used it in my form in JSP:

```
<form action="${baseUrl}/myFormControllerPattern">
```

Comment: i got the solution,but can anyone explain me why the jsp expression threw an error?

Comment: what JSP expression? `"${baseUrl}/myFormControllerPattern"`?

Comment: no. action="<%=baseUrl%>/myFormControllerPattern" this code threw error.

Comment: I'm not sure, but using scriptlets I believe you have to use: `<% request.getAttribute("baseUrl") %>` or something like `<%
pageContext.getAttribute("baseUrl", PageContext.REQUEST_SCOPE);
%>`.

Answer (score 0):

Change form action with javascript instead. Pass `baseUrl` as a model variable in your spring controller and use a javascript function like this to change form action:

```
function changeAction () {
    var baseUrl = "${baseUrl}";
    var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
    form.action = baseUrl;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you jelies, I found the solution  using your method partially. I set the variable in model and used directly in the url as action="${baseUrl}/myPattern"

Comment: So, answer your own question, and accept it! :) I'm glad my answer was useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

try to use javascript/jQuery trick:

```
var curl = document.location.pathname;
    curl = curl.substring(0, curl.indexOf(".html"));
```

the first row will take your app address, then you cut the ".html" substring, thus enabling to add "/myFormControllerPattern" to the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

c:url tag can be usefull

include to jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

and then

```
<form id="myForm" action="<c:url value="/myFormControllerPattern" />" name="myForm">
```